# Mysql - query table with over 10m data

Tags: mysql, sql, bigdata

I am maintaining a web project using Java & mysql.

One mysql table has over 10 million records, I did partition the table by date, so that to reduce rows in each partition. Indexes are also added properly according to queries.

In most query, only the first 1 or 2 partition is used, and the sum of records in those used partitions are less than 200m, it's still pretty quick.

But a few of the queries need to load over 10 partitions to do some statictis, thus over 10m records is involved in a single query, this is quite slow, and it becomes worse as data grows.

Part of the table:

```
id(int), amount(double), type(varchar), user_id(int), event_date(timestamp)
-- `id` is primary key, `type` has index,
```

One of the big query is similar to:

```
select count(id), sum(amount) group by (type)
where event_date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31 23:59:59' and amount >= 10

-- The start & end datetime and the amount range might change.
```

**My question is:**

How to make the query that involves over 10m records quicker?

Here is my guess, but not sure:

- Use mysql cluster? (I never used that before.)
- Use big cache. (Memcache, but the big query is not frequently used.)

Comment: ok; what query does? have you thought about setting up multiple tables and limiting amount of rows per table? For example, each month new table_month_year

Comment: @Andrew I updated the question with table & query info. Your suggestion is good for some query, but still there is a query need to statistics on all data in a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several other things you can do for performance improvement.

- Analyze the query and introduce indexes as required.
- Identify data access pattern of the application and you can cache only the frequently accessed data to reduce disk I/O.

Comment: I already added indexes quite carefully according to queries, and yes I cached some data in the newest 1 or 2 partition, but the query I metioned involve a lot data most of which are not frequently used, so can't cache all of them.

Comment: @EricWang , if those are statistical analysis query as your question suggests, what about scheduling those tasks in the application level ? Notify user once it is run and data is ready. So that it doesn't have to run quickly, considering the data load related.

Comment: Thanks for tip, I am thinking am make the statistics be cached, but It's triggered by user from GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I would shoot for doing some pre-aggregations and store them as tables if the old data is static.  Then have your initial queries based on the pre-aggregate tables and once someone wants more detail, then go to the granular level of the data.  You could create many different summary / aggregate tables, even if you do grouping by say 2-3 fields (not knowing your data cotext/structures).

But consider this...  If you have 10m records, and you do aggregate data for all static / old data grouped on say... 3 fields, and this reduces the set down to even 1 million records, that helps.  Then, if you were interested in totals on just one of the criteria, then you could query the aggregate by 3 fields but group by 1, so your 1m records is the basis of the query and not the full 10.  Once a user finds a particular need of intersection of fieldX=??? and fieldY=???, then go to your 10m record set for the full raw data that may be desired.

Answer (score 0):

What type of partition applied on the date field? Is it range type? If you would have used WRONG partition type like hash then it will look for almost all partition and result in no use for partition.